# Azure devops Workitem types API not returning the only types configured in process in Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Azure DevOps is not retuning the only workitem types I have configured for my process. It also gives with some extra work item types

**API :**

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitemtypes?api-version=5.1
```

**Doc:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20item%20types/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Eg,

**Returned:**

```
Issue
Epic
Task
Test Case
Test Plan
Test Suite
Shared Steps
Shared Parameter
Code Review Request
Code Review Response
Feedback Request
Feedback Response
```

**Expected :**  (only these types)

```
Issue
Epic
Task
```

If there is any other API that returns the only types as shown in azure devops while creating a new workitem in boards, pls let me know

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**API:**

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/{proj_name}/_apis/wit/workItemTypeCategories?api-version=5.1
```

**Response:**

JSON Array with work item types,

```
{
"count": 15,
"value": [
    {
        "name": "Bug Category",
        "referenceName": "Microsoft.BugCategory",
        "defaultWorkItemType": {
            "name": "Bug",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug"
        },
        "workItemTypes": [
            {
                "name": "Bug",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Bug"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypeCategories/Microsoft.BugCategory"
    },
    {
        "name": "Epic Category",
        "referenceName": "Microsoft.EpicCategory",
        "defaultWorkItemType": {
            "name": "Epic",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Epic"
        },
        "workItemTypes": [
            {
                "name": "Epic",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Epic"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypeCategories/Microsoft.EpicCategory"
    },
    {
        "name": "Feature Category",
        "referenceName": "Microsoft.FeatureCategory",
        "defaultWorkItemType": {
            "name": "Feature",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Feature"
        },
        "workItemTypes": [
            {
                "name": "Feature",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Feature"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypeCategories/Microsoft.FeatureCategory"
    },
    {
        "name": "Requirement Category",
        "referenceName": "Microsoft.RequirementCategory",
        "defaultWorkItemType": {
            "name": "User Story",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.UserStory"
        },
        "workItemTypes": [
            {
                "name": "User Story",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.UserStory"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypeCategories/Microsoft.RequirementCategory"
    },
    {
        "name": "Test Case Category",
        "referenceName": "Microsoft.TestCaseCategory",
        "defaultWorkItemType": {
            "name": "Test Case",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.TestCase"
        },
        "workItemTypes": [
            {
                "name": "Test Case",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.TestCase"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypeCategories/Microsoft.TestCaseCategory"
    },
    {
        "name": "Shared Step Category",
        "referenceName": "Microsoft.SharedStepCategory",
        "defaultWorkItemType": {
            "name": "Shared Steps",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.SharedStep"
        },
        "workItemTypes": [
            {
                "name": "Shared Steps",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.SharedStep"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypeCategories/Microsoft.SharedStepCategory"
    },
    {
        "name": "Shared Parameter Category",
        "referenceName": "Microsoft.SharedParameterCategory",
        "defaultWorkItemType": {
            "name": "Shared Parameter",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.SharedParameter"
        },
        "workItemTypes": [
            {
                "name": "Shared Parameter",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.SharedParameter"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypeCategories/Microsoft.SharedParameterCategory"
    },
    {
        "name": "Code Review Request Category",
        "referenceName": "Microsoft.CodeReviewRequestCategory",
        "defaultWorkItemType": {
            "name": "Code Review Request",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.CodeReviewRequest"
        },
        "workItemTypes": [
            {
                "name": "Code Review Request",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.CodeReviewRequest"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypeCategories/Microsoft.CodeReviewRequestCategory"
    },
    {
        "name": "Code Review Response Category",
        "referenceName": "Microsoft.CodeReviewResponseCategory",
        "defaultWorkItemType": {
            "name": "Code Review Response",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.CodeReviewResponse"
        },
        "workItemTypes": [
            {
                "name": "Code Review Response",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.CodeReviewResponse"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypeCategories/Microsoft.CodeReviewResponseCategory"
    },
    {
        "name": "Feedback Request Category",
        "referenceName": "Microsoft.FeedbackRequestCategory",
        "defaultWorkItemType": {
            "name": "Feedback Request",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.FeedbackRequest"
        },
        "workItemTypes": [
            {
                "name": "Feedback Request",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.FeedbackRequest"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypeCategories/Microsoft.FeedbackRequestCategory"
    },
    {
        "name": "Feedback Response Category",
        "referenceName": "Microsoft.FeedbackResponseCategory",
        "defaultWorkItemType": {
            "name": "Feedback Response",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.FeedbackResponse"
        },
        "workItemTypes": [
            {
                "name": "Feedback Response",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.FeedbackResponse"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypeCategories/Microsoft.FeedbackResponseCategory"
    },
    {
        "name": "Test Plan Category",
        "referenceName": "Microsoft.TestPlanCategory",
        "defaultWorkItemType": {
            "name": "Test Plan",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.TestPlan"
        },
        "workItemTypes": [
            {
                "name": "Test Plan",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.TestPlan"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypeCategories/Microsoft.TestPlanCategory"
    },
    {
        "name": "Test Suite Category",
        "referenceName": "Microsoft.TestSuiteCategory",
        "defaultWorkItemType": {
            "name": "Test Suite",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.TestSuite"
        },
        "workItemTypes": [
            {
                "name": "Test Suite",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.TestSuite"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypeCategories/Microsoft.TestSuiteCategory"
    },
    {
        "name": "Task Category",
        "referenceName": "Microsoft.TaskCategory",
        "defaultWorkItemType": {
            "name": "Task",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Task"
        },
        "workItemTypes": [
            {
                "name": "Task",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.Task"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypeCategories/Microsoft.TaskCategory"
    },
    {
        "name": "Hidden Types Category",
        "referenceName": "Microsoft.HiddenCategory",
        "defaultWorkItemType": {
            "name": "Code Review Request",
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.CodeReviewRequest"
        },
        "workItemTypes": [
            {
                "name": "Code Review Request",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.CodeReviewRequest"
            },
            {
                "name": "Code Review Response",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.CodeReviewResponse"
            },
            {
                "name": "Feedback Request",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.FeedbackRequest"
            },
            {
                "name": "Feedback Response",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.FeedbackResponse"
            },
            {
                "name": "Shared Steps",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.SharedStep"
            },
            {
                "name": "Shared Parameter",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.SharedParameter"
            },
            {
                "name": "Test Plan",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.TestPlan"
            },
            {
                "name": "Test Suite",
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Microsoft.VSTS.WorkItemTypes.TestSuite"
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/def0f1fb-8a14-43d2-a829-9307e3c549cd/_apis/wit/workItemTypeCategories/Microsoft.HiddenCategory"
    }
]
```

}

**The last index of the `value` Array contains the workitem types that will not be visible in AZD while creating a new workitem.**

Therefore in my case, I had to manually iterate the workitem types present in the last index and removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get Backlogconfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/backlogconfiguration/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest api to get the work item types in each backlog level.

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/work/backlogconfiguration?api-version=5.1`

It will only return work item types(ie.Issue, Epic, Task) that are shown in azure devops boards.

Update:

If you have customized work item types. You may need to add your custom work item types to a backlog. Or create a `new top level Portfolio backlogs` to hold your custom work item type See below:

1, Go to organization settings-->Process-->Select the inherited process-->Backlog levels tab

[image]

2, Add custom work item type to a backlog, or create a **new top level Portfolio backlog**:

Click the 3dots of the backlog you want to add the custom work item type-->Check the cutom work item type you want to add. See below:

[image]

Comment: Hi Levi,
This API response doesn't contain my custom created workitem types

Comment: If you have customized work item types. You may need to add your custom work item types to a backlog. See above update.

Comment: Hi @ArunJoshla How did it go now?

Comment: Hi @Levi,
This doesn't work for me 'cause my integration should not make extra changes in AZD. I have decided to use the following `https://dev.azure.com/test/Agile Project/_apis/wit/workItemTypeCategories?api-version=5.1` to get the workitem types and the last value in the array contains the types to be hidden. I'm not sure this login will always work. any suggestion?

Comment: Hi @ArunJoshla The above Api you used  is indeed a better solution. You can post out your solution and accept it as answer. Hope it could help others who may encounter the same issue. I checked and found above api exists in all the historical version. I believe it will continue to exist in the future version of api.

Comment: Thanks @Levi for testing the version compatibility :D. I'll write it as answer and mark it as accepted.